# Why does databound property of ASP.NET usercontrol work only without quotes?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, properties

I have a custom ASP.NET user control implemented fully in code-behind. The control has one string property and its declarative markup looks like this:

```
<uc:MyControl ImageUrl="/Content/images/" runat="server" />
```

Most likely the actual declaration will use data binding syntax like this:

```
<uc:MyControl ImageUrl="<%# PageInfo.ImageUrl %>" runat="server" />
```

Now here's the odd part pertaining to my question. If I use the above syntax, the data binding does not work and the value of ImageUrl at run-time is the string literal of whatever is between quotes. However, if I remove the double quotes, it works as expected:

```
<uc:MyControl ImageUrl=<%# PageInfo.ImageUrl %> runat="server" />
```

The same behavior occurs with both double and single quotes. I am puzzled by this and although the code is working it's really not optimal as putting values in quotes is the norm and the approach to make the data binding work is decidedly unorthodox.

Anyone have any ideas on why this only works without quotes?

Comment: PageInfo.ImageUrl is databound to your custom control?

Comment: PageInfo.ImageUrl is an arbitrary property that I am binding to the ImageUrl property of my control in the example. I can use anything else there (Request.QueryString for example) and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Have you tried this?  ImageUrl="<%= PageInfo.ImageUrl %>" runat="server" /> -- or what about setting the property in the code behind?  give your uc:MyControl an ID so you can?

Comment: The data binding syntax I am using is correct. The syntax you are proposing will not work as it is a shortcut for Response.Write and not for data binding.My question is not about how I can set the value of the property, which I can certainly do in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...it was something to do with the file (probably encoding, but not sure). On a whim, I copied the code to a new file and deleted the original. Now the data binding works with the quotes as it should.